# Yahoo finance api for real time quotes

Tags: javascript, cordova, finance, yahoo-finance, stockquotes

I'm implementing a mobile finance app using phonegap. For this I need a real time quotes. After googling for a while I come to know that Yahoo provides real time stock quotes. So I created a 30 days trial account by using [this](http://billing.finance.yahoo.com/realtime_quotes/signup) link. Now I don't know how to proceed further. is there any tutorial or sample code to call Yahoo's rest web services to get real time stock quotes using phonegap?

Answer (score 1):

The [Yahoo! Developer Network](http://developer.yahoo.com/), specifically their [Finance](http://developer.yahoo.com/finance/) section, appears to be their only officially support real-time solution, according to [this post from Feb 2009](http://developer.yahoo.com/forum/General-Discussion-at-YDN/Stock-Quote-API-returning-commas-in/1234765072000-6036c128-a7e0-3aa5-9e72-1af1871e1b41). 
But, that information could obviously be outdated.